# RXJava2. Do I need dispose streams which emits once? (Single, Maybe)

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a lot of `Single`'s in my code, such as

```
Disposable disp = Single.fromCallable(()-> loadData())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(res-> showInUI(res),
                    throwable -> Log.e(TAG, throwable.getMessage()))
            );
```

As I understood from the documentation, the difference between `Observable` and `Single` is that Single can respond with an error, Never respond, Respond with a success and it emits only once.
Now I do not dispose anywhere and everything works fine.

So do I need to execute `disp.dispose()` at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, indeed, it doesn't matter whether it is `Single`/`Observable`/`Completable`.
It is matter as you don't want to keep your UI bound to a some background work, that will leak your Activity.
It's also matter cause you don't want to get notification at the UI beyond some point (after your `Activity` destroyed for instance) that can cause NPEs or other problems. 
Besides that, it's a good practive to cancel and stop expensive background work when user leave/close the `Activity`/`Screen` is in, in order to clear resources.
All of those considerations are common to all `Observable` types.